# Bootstrap (2) nav targets aren't updated when links are outside nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.x. I've used a tabbed navigation and it's working well, provided the links used to move between the tabs are on the `.nav-tabs` themselves.

If I put a link the main `body` which refers to a link/target within the `.nav-tabs` list/menu, the content loads fine.

However, the `.nav-tabs` themselves don't change. That is to say a new tab and content shows, which is great, but since the `.nav-tabs` don't update two things occur:

1. The wrong tab is active.
2. The active `.nav` link doesn't work. So say I went from tab `href="#nav-a"` to tab `href="#nav-b"` but from a link in the main content and not in the `.nav-tabs` the link for `#nav-a` stays active (and not clickable), preventing me from returning to it.

Should I be using `data-spy` or something like that?

Comment: I think posting the link or at least some code to look at would help. Also, there's no need to include 'thank you's in your post.

Comment: The site is here: [site](http://conference.lceeq.ca) - Essentially it works as expected - until you start using links within the tabs which refer to other tabs. The best example is to click on the "For Students" page. At the end of the short description is a link to the second tab with the rules. If you click that link you can't return to the first student page. The `.nav-tabs` stay in their state from the first tab display.

Comment: So I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814481/linking-to-a-bootstrap-tab-from-outside-how-to-set-the-tab-to-active?rq=1 But I realize I'm using both tabs and drop-down menus altogether so the appropriate tab is active… not the right drop down menu…

Comment: When you have more information for your post, it's typically best to just edit your post so that the information is all in one place.