# Clicking on logo redirects to a specific Bootstrap Tab and makes it active

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I read pretty much all related posts in order to find a solution to my simple problem, but with little success.

What I want is simple: when a user clicks on the brand (logo), it should redirect him to a specific tab and also make it **active** (clicked).

Can someone show me how can this be done?

Brand:

```
    <div class="navbar-header">            
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#menu2" data-toggle="tab" ><img 
src="includes/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"></a>
  </div>
```

Main:

```
<div class="container">
         <section id="main" >
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs right-to-left" id="myTab" >
               <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"></a></li>
               <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu0"></a></li>
               <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"></a></li>
               <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"></a></li>
               <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3"></a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
               <div id="menu0" class="tab-pane fade in active">
               <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
               <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
               <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
```

Currently I managed to open the tab with this line of code:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">
```

What else do I need to also make the #menu2 tab active?

EDIT:
Tried the solution here:
[Linking to a Bootstrap Tab from outside - how to set the tab to “active”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814481/linking-to-a-bootstrap-tab-from-outside-how-to-set-the-tab-to-active)
but still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to a Bootstrap Tab from outside - how to set the tab to "active"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814481/linking-to-a-bootstrap-tab-from-outside-how-to-set-the-tab-to-active)

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bootstrap. Open the certain tab by clicking on the link at the page

### 1. By clicking on the Logo and Navbar's items

I've set up the logo, the menus and tabs. Now each of these switches the text panels.

I've used links with `data-toggle="tab"` everywhere. And I've wrote the script, which coordinates the active items in `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` and `<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">`.

Please check the result:

http://www.bootply.com/Nz8uh6pWC6

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var CLASS_NAVBAR    = '.navbar .navbar-nav';
  var CLASS_NAV_TABS  = '#myTab';
  var CLASS_LI_ACTIVE = '>li[class="active"]';

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var classTarget   = '>li>a[href="' + $(e.target).attr( 'href' ) + '"]';
    var selectNavbar  = $( CLASS_NAVBAR   + classTarget );
    var selectNavTabs = $( CLASS_NAV_TABS + classTarget );

    if ( !selectNavbar.parent().hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
      $( CLASS_NAVBAR + CLASS_LI_ACTIVE ).removeClass( 'active' );
      selectNavbar.parent().addClass( 'active' );
    }

    if ( !selectNavTabs.parent().hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
      $( CLASS_NAV_TABS + CLASS_LI_ACTIVE ).removeClass( 'active' );
      selectNavTabs.parent().addClass( 'active' );
    }
  })
});
```

```css
 @import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.panel {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-top-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu0">Menu 0</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>  

<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs right-to-left" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu0">Menu 0</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content panel panel-default">
      <div id="menu0" class="tab-pane fade in active"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 0</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 1</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 2</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 3</h4></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### 2. By clicking on the Logo only

http://www.bootply.com/xFNf7m2SiG

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var CLASS_NAV_TABS  = '#myTab';
  var CLASS_LI_ACTIVE = '>li[class="active"]';

  $( 'a.navbar-brand' ).click( function (e) {
    var selectNavTabs = $( CLASS_NAV_TABS + '>li>a[href="' + $(e.target).attr( 'href' ) + '"]' );

    if ( !selectNavTabs.parent().hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
      $( CLASS_NAV_TABS + CLASS_LI_ACTIVE ).removeClass( 'active' );
      selectNavTabs.parent().addClass( 'active' );
    }
  })
});
```

```css
 @import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.panel {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-top-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>  

<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs right-to-left" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu0">Menu 0</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content panel panel-default">
      <div id="menu0" class="tab-pane fade in active"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 0</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 1</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 2</h4></div></div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade"><div class="panel-body"><h4>Content 3</h4></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.navbar-brand').on('click', function(){
   $('#menu0').tab('show');
})
```

or

```
$('.navbar-brand').on('click', function(){
   $('#menu0').click();
})
```

from: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Comment: Does the first way show the tab? If not, do you have console errors?

Comment: It shows because I have this line of code:
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">

Comment: The active issue is what bothers me.
No console errors either.